# NiFi Route on JSON Attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

Trying to use NiFi to route on an attribute.
I am attempting to take a json file, where two of the json records contain the following attributes (there are other json documents with different attributes in this file):

```
{
  "ts" : "2020-010-07T12:00:00.448392Z",
  "uid" : "CHh3F30dkfueLhnxSk",
  "id.orig_h" : "10.10.10.10",
  "id.orig_p" : 19726,
  "id.resp_h" : "172.10.10.20",
  "id.resp_p" : 443,
  "proto" : "tcp",
  "conn_state" : "SH",
  "local_orig" : false,
  "local_resp" : false,
  "missed_bytes" : 0,
  "history" : "F",
  "orig_pkts" : 1,
  "orig_ip_bytes" : 52,
  "resp_pkts" : 0,
  "resp_ip_bytes" : 0}
 {
  "ts" : "2020-10-10T12:00:00.461880Z",
  "uid" : "CdoiLnRscrxO1BSYb",
  "id.orig_h" : "10.10.17.777",
  "id.orig_p" : 40433,
  "id.resp_h" : "172.10.10.77",
  "id.resp_p" : 443,
  "version" : "TLSv12",
  "cipher" : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
  "curve" : "secp777r1",
  "server_name" : "connect-stackoverflow.questions.com",
  "resumed" : false,
  "established" : true,
  "cert_chain_fuids" : [ "FR84qjkl2342SZLwV7", "Ffweqiof48b8j" ],
  "client_cert_chain_fuids" : [ ],
  "subject" : "CN=connect-ulastm.bentley.com",
  "issuer" : "CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US",
  "validation_status" : "ok"}
```

I want to specifically route on the $.conn_state attribute but it is not working. I have tried to match the expression with the evaluateJSONpath processor and passed it to routeOnAttribute.  Here are my settings:

evaluateJSONpath processor:
[image]

The above processor does not match the json and forward the document

and the evaluateJSONpath is followed by the routeOnAttribute processor:
[image]

I have attempted to routeOnAttribute directly from my jsonRecord, but it does not appear to pull out or identify the attribute for routing...

How would I do this?

Comment: looks like json is not valid....are you getting the value for conn.state in conn.log as attribute (from json above I think it will be null )..when process json through EvaluateJsonPath?

Comment: it's not a valid json.

Comment: I do not think I am getting the attribute... I updated to split the json out of the file, but the attribute is still not being found.

Answer (score 0):

@Advent United

The JSON sample is more than one object, your evaluateJson is going to expect a single record in matching $.conn_state.   For multiple record work against json or any data stream you should use QueryRecord. Once configured w/ record reader and record writer within in that processor you just click + to create the route and the value is the select statement where conn_state is not null.   Then you can drag that route to the next processor.

Comment: I figured out the problem I was having... It's mostly a work around, so I will try this query Record. My file has almost 400million objects and not all of them are the same. Trying to split each object out and then route to the correct joltJson processor to update the flowfile. My problem appears to be the expression query I used.